# Advice on designing lifecycle method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'd like to design a function that is not triggered by a button click, not onmount, not on unmount but on given set 'times' like below:

```
function () {
 if this time comes: do this
 also if this comes: do this
 and if this time comes: do this
 any time that is not one of the times above: do nothing
}
```

i currently, the options i know i have are using the useEffect hook, or setInterval, but am not sure if they can work, i dont know how to do it either. kindly suggest on how i can achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval is great for executing a function at regular intervals. for instance:

```
function sayHelloWorld() {
    console.log('Hello, World!');
}

// interval in milliseconds --> 1000ms = 1 sec...
const sayOverAndOver = setInterval(sayHelloWorld, 1000);
```

After 1 second and each second thereafter, the console will log 'Hello, World!'

Some good resources with great explainers on setInterval, etc. are W3Schools, GeeksForGeeks, and Mozilla MDN. I tried to link to them here, but the text editor on here is buggy.

Cheers!

Comment: thanks @patrick, actually, after asking here i went to W3schools, and i foundt out that setTimout() is what i needed, however, setInterval too, is useful, and i will use it some where in my code